# Compare all values of an Array of Objects with an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have the following data:

```js
const myArr = [{
  id: 0,
  company: "microsoft",
  location: "berlin"
}, {
  id: 1,
  company: "google",
  location: "london"
}, {
  id: 2,
  company: "twitter",
  location: "berlin"
}];

let myObj = {
  company: ["google", "twitter"],
  location: ["london"]
}
```

and given that the `myObj.company` entries are changing (irrelevant how) I am trying to create a function that filters results and only returns Objects that satisfy the `location` and `company` criteria.

In the example above, what we need returned is :

```
{ 
  id: 1,
  company: "google",
  location: "london"
}
```

If `myObj` was

```
let myObj = {
  company: ["google", "twitter"],
  location: []
}
```

then the returned result should be

```
{ 
  id: 1,
  company: "google",
  location: "london"
},
{ 
  id: 2,
  company: "twitter",
  location: "berlin"
}
```

Comment: What's the expected result of that example you gave??

Comment: What is the problem with your iteration? Please add the code you've tried to the question too.

Comment: just rephrased my question. , will edit it more.

Comment: [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) + [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Thanks for all the amazing answers, I wasn't expecting such a feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.filter`, `Array.prototype.every` and `Object.keys` to get the desired result like this: (note that `obj` could have any number of keys, it flexible that way)

```js
const myArr = [{
  id: 0,
  company: "microsoft",
  location: "berlin"
}, {
  id: 1,
  company: "google",
  location: "london"
}, {
  id: 2,
  company: "twitter",
  location: "berlin"
}];

let myObj = {
  company: ["google", "twitter"],
  location: ["london"]
}

function find(arr, obj) {
  // get only the keys from obj that their corresponding array is not empty
  var keys = Object.keys(obj).filter(k => obj[k].length !== 0);

  // return a filtered array of objects that ...
  return arr.filter(o => {
    // ... met the creteria (for every key k in obj, the current object o must have its value of the key k includded in the array obj[k])
    return keys.every(k => {
      return obj[k].indexOf(o[k]) != -1;   
    });
  });
}

console.log(find(myArr, myObj));
```

Comment: Thank you, selecting as correct because: 1/ comments 2/ avoiding unnecessary loops 3/ readable

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method(for old browser support use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method)

```
myArr.filter(o => (myObj.company.length == 0 || myObj.company.includes(o.company)) && (myObj.location.length == 0 || myObj.location.includes(o.location)))
```

```js
const myArr = [{
  id: 0,
  company: "microsoft",
  location: "berlin"
}, {
  id: 1,
  company: "google",
  location: "london"
}, {
  id: 2,
  company: "twitter",
  location: "berlin"
}];

let myObj = {
  company: ["google", "twitter"],
  location: ["london"]
}

console.log(
  myArr.filter(o => (myObj.company.length == 0 || myObj.company.includes(o.company)) && (myObj.location.length == 0 || myObj.location.includes(o.location)))
)

myObj = {
  company: ["google", "twitter"],
  location: []
}

console.log(
  myArr.filter(o => (myObj.company.length == 0 || myObj.company.includes(o.company)) && (myObj.location.length == 0 || myObj.location.includes(o.location)))
)
```

---

**UPDATE :** In case there an n number of properties collection then you need to make some variation, where you can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) methods.

```
var keys = Object.keys(myObj);

myArr.filter(o => keys.every(k => myObj[k].length == 0 || myObj[k].includes(o[k])))
```

```js
const myArr = [{
  id: 0,
  company: "microsoft",
  location: "berlin"
}, {
  id: 1,
  company: "google",
  location: "london"
}, {
  id: 2,
  company: "twitter",
  location: "berlin"
}];

let myObj = {
  company: ["google", "twitter"],
  location: ["london"]
}

var keys = Object.keys(myObj);
console.log(
  myArr.filter(o => keys.every(k => myObj[k].length == 0 || myObj[k].includes(o[k])))
)

myObj = {
  company: ["google", "twitter"],
  location: []
}
keys = Object.keys(myObj);
console.log(
  myArr.filter(o => keys.every(k => myObj[k].length == 0 || myObj[k].includes(o[k])))
)
```

Comment: thank you. I'm upvoting because 1) didn't know `includes` ! 2) simplicity and brevity as well as readability.. comment : you are testing every array separately (location, company) so if I have 2-3 different tables with other data it's not going to be so DRY

Answer (score 1):

You could filter with iterating the keys of criteria and check the content for equality of if the length of the array is not zero.

```js
const filterBy = (array, criteria) => array.filter(o => 
    Object.keys(criteria).every(k =>
        criteria[k].some(c => c === o[k]) || !criteria[k].length)
);

const myArr = [{ id: 0, company: "microsoft", location: "berlin" }, { id: 1, company: "google", location: "london" }, { id: 2, company: "twitter", location: "berlin" }];

console.log(filterBy(myArr, { company: ["google", "twitter"], location: ["london"] }));
console.log(filterBy(myArr, { company: ["google", "twitter"], location: [] }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead of [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const filterBy = (array, criteria) => array.filter(o => 
    Object.keys(criteria).every(k => criteria[k].includes(o[k]) || !criteria[k].length)
);

const myArr = [{ id: 0, company: "microsoft", location: "berlin" }, { id: 1, company: "google", location: "london" }, { id: 2, company: "twitter", location: "berlin" }];

console.log(filterBy(myArr, { company: ["google", "twitter"], location: ["london"] }));
console.log(filterBy(myArr, { company: ["google", "twitter"], location: [] }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: +1 because of the console-wrapper hack :) as well as the very scalable solution, amazing! it does take me a while to read through all those nested array functions though, and in the end we're using, `filter`, `keys`, `every` *and* `some` so I'm left wondering if there's a more verbose but also readable way of doing it